# What are the possible ways through which all caches can be disabled?

Tags: magento2, cache

In one of our project website started loading very slow and I found out all caches were disabled which I have enabled earlier.

I can figure out the following ways through which caches can get disabled:

- When someone runs `php bin/magento cache:disable` command.
- When someone modifies `app/etc/env.php` and disables caches from there.
- Under certain circumstances a file .regenerate is written in the var folder (either at setup upgrade or composer install / upgrade) and if that file is present when running `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` the cache is disabled and re-enabled when the compilation process is finished. For some reason, sometimes the cache is not re-enabled. (Referenced from [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/264421/9169))

What are the other possibilities through which

- Someone having code/db access can disable it ?
- Automatically it can get disabled ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In developer mode the option on backend is available to disable any cache from backend

Whereas in production mode, this option is not available, so you need to do it by command.

To disable all cache you need to run this as you already added in question:

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

And if you need to disable on cache, then disable it by it's tag name

Example:

```
magento cache:disable full_page
```

There is no database entry for these cache types, if you disable any cache from command, then it will update entry in `env.php`, and if you do it from admin then this method will also update entry in `env.php`

You wont find any other way to disable cache. You can disable it either **from shell** or **from admin** or directly **from env.php**

Hope this is the answer of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue in Magento 2.2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17634

> In this path:
>   `magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Code/GeneratedFiles.php`.
>   This is the code which disables the cache other than scenarios you
>   mentioned in your answer

```
$deploymentConfig = $this->directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::CONFIG);
            $configPool = new ConfigFilePool();
            $envPath = $deploymentConfig . '/' . $configPool->getPath(ConfigFilePool::APP_ENV);
            if ($this->write->isExist($this->write->getRelativePath($envPath))) {
                $enabledCacheTypes = $this->getEnabledCacheTypes();
                $this->disableAllCacheTypes();
            }
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Unfortunately I have mentioned it in my third scenario.

Comment: @amitshree so have you removed the code or updated your magento version? It may be the cause and also you mentioned in your question by asking the code which influence the cache

Comment: I have not removed the code or updated Magento version. I have disabled Inventory modules starting with `Magento_Inventory` and afterwards I ran upgrade, di compile and static content deployment commands.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not the best practices to disable your Inventory modules. I would not rate it as permanent and proper solution. Anyways it's up to you, every body has their own opinion and way of doing things

Comment: One of the optimization tips of Magneto is that **disable modules which are not used/required for you project**. Why not disable Magento_Inventory modules?

Comment: Yes you can disable `Magento_Inventory` modules in order to speed up the upgrade process for merchants migrating from 2.0.x, 2.1.x, or 2.2.x to 2.3.x but my point is how it is related to your question cache automatically disabled issue ? So I am talking about specifically your question issue

Comment: I am not able to discuss anymore on this topic. Glad you solved your problem and just wanted to help you. keep coding :) thanks :)

Comment: Well, I have not disabled Inventory modules to fix this issue. I have disabled it to optimize the website only. After disabling I ran upgrade, di compile commands which  might have caused the issue but I am not sure. So trying to figure out other possibilities through which caches might be disabled as I saw this issue next day of running those commands. I am not sure it was because of those commands or there is any other reason. Anyway thanks for your efforts. Happy coding :)